# DocuSign Multiple templates as one pdf

Tags: docusignapi

I have been working with composite templates to generate an envelope from multiple templates (Template-A, Template-B).

It generates one envelope as expected, however, it shows up as two pdfs in the signer's email attachment: DocumentFromTemplate-A.pdf and DocumentFromTemplateB.pdf.

Using DocuSign API, how do I just have the user see both template documents in one pdf?

So ideally, the email would have combineddocument.pdf with both template documents one after the other.

Comment: I don't think this is directly supported, but I will check with a colleague to confirm. As an alternative, your integration could download the combined documents and Certificate of Completion, and email that to the signer(s).

Comment: Agreed @Larry K I do not believe the email notification attachments can be modified to have a combined PDF. The DocuSign WebApp and API can however grab all the docs as a combined PDF.

Comment: The alternative mentioned, is the download only possible after the signers have completed signing? Or could integration download, combine it into one pdf and send it to signers for signing?

Comment: continued.....The reason we have it as 2 templates is explained below : Template-A is the application form template for signing. While template-B is the template for appendix to attach along with the form. Our code might generate multiple documents from template-B based on volume of appendix data. So ideally we were planning to have docFromTemp-A, Doc1FromTemp-B, Doc2FromTemp-B...sent to user as on document. Please also suggest if there are better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

to summarize the answer:

can't merge documents directly using the DocuSign platform/APIs.
You can do that yourself in your application and upload the new combined document to replace the existing one.